# How to visualize Image gradient in Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing

[image]

[image]

How to visualize the image gradient of this picture in Python, like the pic above?

Comment: please go through the following link. it gives a good description of how you can detect this using opencv in Cpp

http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3016/how-to-detect-gradients-in-images
i have individaully tried the same and could get the results at my end. For some reason, it is not letting me to add answers, so putting it here.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by image gradient. The black and white image you provided has a constant negative gradient going down the image, and an average gradient of zero going across it.
Is your intention to visualise the gradient in 3D? Or do you want to plot the gradient going down the image on average?

Comment: @SauravMondal, answering the image is put on hold until the author clarifies his meaning. It prevents people like us from wasting time attempting to guess what the author means.

Comment: I've just added a pic, what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

- Use the Pyton Imaging Library PIL (http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)
- Load the image using `Image.open` and read the colors of each pixel into a 2D list using `Image.getpixel` (http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm). One of the three RGB values will do because the image is grayscale thus the R, B, and G values of each pixel are equal to each other.
- Calculate the gradient for each pixel except of those at the edge:
  `grad[x][y] = [(list[x+1][y]-list[x-1][y])/2.0, (list[x][y+1]-list[x][y-1])/2.0]`
  (Note that the gradient is a 2D vector. It has an x and a y value.)
- Create a quiver plot e.g. with MatPlotLib's PyPlot (https://www.getdatajoy.com/examples/python-plots/vector-fields)

Also check this document where a gradient function from numpy is used: http://elektromagnetisme.no/2011/09/12/calculating-the-gradient-in-python/